# Notice: Undefined property: java_Client::$cancelProxyCreationTag in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 1994

Tags: java, tomcat, jasperserver, php-java-bridge

I'm trying to use Jasper report with a PHP yii application. I've already installed jasper-report-server with obviouslly tomcat and apache with php. I've already make the configuration to download the reports and I'm having this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new org.altic.jasperReports.JdbcConnection. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altic.jasperReports.JdbcConnection
```

Screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

> Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new org.altic.jasperReports.JdbcConnection. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altic.jasperReports.JdbcConnection VM: 1.7.0_101@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-10 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702) #-9 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547) #-8 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) #-7 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) #-6 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) #-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445) #-4 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) #-3 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500) #-2 php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145) #-1 php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60) #0 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc(232): java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(4, 'php.java.bridge...', 'T', false) #1 http://localho in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195]

Comment: I've installed again JavaBridge and Jasper and now is working. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, and I solved it ***initializing manually the `cancelProxyCreationTag` property***, when creating JasperCompileManager :

```
$compileManager = new \JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
$compileManager->__client->cancelProxyCreationTag = 0;
```

The `cancelProxyCreationTag` is a property that is used but not declared nor initialized in the Java.inc generated file...

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` indicates that a Java class is not present on the java bridge server side (generally in the deployed servlet / .war file).

Without the code I cannot give a precise answer, but it looks your JDBC intialization is not correct in some way. Maybe you forgot to include the JDBC driver in the deployed servlet (for example the mysql jdbc connector...) or didn't pass a correctly initialized `org.altic.jasperReports.JdbcConnection` object.

---

*Concerning the notice message `java_Client::$cancelProxyCreationTag`. It shouldn't be the cause of the problem, it's actually a missing property on the java_Client reached whenever the client unregister its instance (for example on uncaught exception). This notice message is linked to the Java.inc client, for an alternative reworked client see also the [soluble/japha client on github](https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha), it's compatible with the php/java bridge 6.2.1 and provides some fixes and enhancements on the original client. See also my comment for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651573/how-to-fix-notice-undefined-property-java-clientprotocol-in-http-local/38942604#38942604)*